# Custom config value Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I have a problem getting value from `config/app.php` in Laravel 5.5

I added a custom line:

```
'test' => '12345',
```

Then I try to get it in my controller like this:

```
 config(app.test);
```

and it returns nothing but when I try to get `config(app.locale);`

It returns `en`

What I'm doing wrong? Are there any commands that I have to run after editing the config file?

Comment: Try running `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Try running `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: @SougataBoseThe command should not be run during local development as configuration options will frequently need to be changed during the course of your application's development - that's what they say in documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the command:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,In laravel you can add custom value in config/constants.php
eg:- "test" => "1234", you can access by this, Config::get('constants.test');

Comment: Config::get() is for older versions and it still not working :(

Comment: \Config::get('constants.test'); this is working fine just tested

Comment: @DmitryMalys it isn't for "older versions" it is for all versions, its the same exact class instance being used in the helper and facade

Comment: @lagbox sorry my friend it is true :) i just need to run config:clear command